# Will citation data be lost when an article is deleted from a google scholar profile

Tags: publications, google-scholar

**Problem** I recently found that another author's publications were automatically added to my profile. We do share first initial and last name, but not middle initials or first name. We also happen to publish in the same domain.

**Potential Solution** I found that I can delete those publications from my profile. The only thing I am wondering is whether the article will remain on google scholar with all citation data, or will this be lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you remove a paper from your Google Scholar profile you are not deleting any data. Google scholar only allows you to claim authorship and choose if you want to list a certain record on your profile or not.

Comment: Appreciate the quick help!